# Read show create table in mysql stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures

How can I read the output of following query and assign to a stored procedure's variable?

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE users;
```

Or, is there is an information schema from where I can draw the full table structure my querying with a table name?